# Cordova inAppBrowser opens www.google.com but not my custom facebook login page?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am working on a Cordova based mobile app.

I want to open a facebook login page in InAppBrowser.

Below is my code to open the page

```
$scope.InAppBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://onboarding.roialty.com/social/facebook/start?login_key=login_key', '_blank', 'location=no');
$scope.InAppBrowser.show();
```

But it opens to a white blank page.

When I edit the link to `www.google.com` then it opens in the browser. But it does not open my facebook login link.

I have also tried adding

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

in the whitelist but still not working.

Anything I am doing wrong?

**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Your device doesn't trust your server certificate. Make sure you have latest webview update, there was a bug that prevented a lot of sites to appear as untrusted

Comment: I am using android v 5.1.1 and inappbrowser v 1.6.1 and how do I update my webview?

Comment: In your phone, open Play Store app, go to my apps and check available updates

Comment: ok thanks will check after downloading but what if the issue is in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried allow-navigation option of Whitelisting. 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/