# InAppBrowser not loading website because of SSL certificate

Tags: ionic-framework, ssl-certificate, inappbrowser

I have an Ionic 5.x app with the InAppBrowser plugin. I am trying to load a website with the plugin, the browser opens but the page is completely blank and with no errors thrown.

After many hours of debugging I have concluded that the issue is the certificate of the website not being trusted.

What does not make sense is the website is secure when viewed on a browser and is "Verified by: DigiCert Inc"

Other questions with same issue:
[Loading url in ionic shows blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158188/loading-url-in-ionic-shows-blank-screen),
[Cordova inAppBrowser opens www.google.com but not my custom facebook login page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098201/cordova-inappbrowser-opens-www-google-com-but-not-my-custom-facebook-login-page)

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

The code I am using to open:

```js
this.browser = this.inAppBrowser.create( "https://mywebsite.com/", "_blank", "location=yes" );
this.browser.on("loadstart").subscribe( event => {
  console.log( event ); // not triggered
});
this.browser.on("loadstop").subscribe( event => {
  console.log( event ); // triggered
});
this.browser.on("loaderror").subscribe( event => {
  console.log( event ); // not triggered
});
```

Comment: will be helpfull if you share some code of opening in app browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many many hours of digging around I was finally able to find a solution. Editing a plugin file is not ideal but it does fix this issue!

Edit this file: `plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/src/android/InAppBrowser.java`

Add this to the import section:

```js
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
```

Then add this to the `InAppBrowserClient` class ( around line 1224 ):

```js
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
    return;
}
```

Comment: This solution turned out to have it's own issue of Google Play declining the .apk due to security issues. For this small project that was not an issue but shortly after the hosting company found they had installed the certificate without the intermediate cert, this solved the ssl issue all together.

Comment: Ignoring SSL errors won't solve the root cause and opens up your app for security holes.

Answer (score 1):

1. In file "plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\src\android\InAppBrowser.java":
   Add this lines to import section:

   ```js
   import android.net.http.SslError;
   import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
   ```
2. Add this to the `InAppBrowserClient` class ( around line 1224 ):

   ```js
   public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
       handler.proceed();
       return;
   }
   ```
3. In Console of Project Root: execute

   ```
   $ cordova platform remove android
   $ cordova platform add android
   ```

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers